# Server don't take cookies from http request

Tags: java, android, cookies

I'm developing an app for porting on mobile a business application. About cookies, i store them in sharedPreferences, and when application is launched, check this, take the cookie if there, put into a cookieStore, and put cookieStore into httpContext `_myContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);`. This context is send as parameter in httpClient.execute(request, myContext). Now, i check in debug mode the values of context, cookie, cookieStore response ecc, and ALL VALUES is correct, but the server, response me as i haven't logged in. Someone can help me? Here the code that manage cookies:

private static HttpContext handleCookieStore() {

```
try {

        if (_myContext == null ) {

            _myContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        }

        // Instantiate and fill cookieStore
        CookieStore cookieStore = (CookieStore)_myContext.getAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE);

        if ( cookieStore == null ) {

            // Instantiate new coockieStore
            cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();


            // Instantiate utility class
            Utility utility = new Utility(_sharedPref);

            Map<String, ?> sessionCookie = utility.getSessionCookie();

            // Look for existing cookies into sharing pref
            if( sessionCookie != null ) {

                // Instantiate a map of string for iterate on cookie's values saved in sharedPref
                Map<String, ?> cookies = sessionCookie;

                // Take all the keys
                Object [] keys = cookies.keySet().toArray();

                for (int i=0; i<cookies.size(); i++ ) { 

                    String name = (String) keys[i];
                    String value = (String) cookies.get(keys[i]);

                    Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie( name , value );

                    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
                }

                // Set store to context
                _myContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

            } else {
                //

                _myContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
            }

        } else {
            Utility utility = new Utility(_sharedPref);

            // Read the existing cookies
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();

            for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {

                System.out.println("c = " + cookie.getName() + " : " + cookie.getValue());

                // Save cookie value into shared preferences
                utility.saveSessionCookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue() );
            }

        }

} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e("exception->CustomHttpClient.handleCookie", " " + e);
    return null;
}
// Return current context
return _myContext;
```

}

Thanks in advance to all!